# jQuery - Responsive panel

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, panel

I want to reveal a panel on my page on page loading. I got this already with a script.

But when the site loads, the panel reveals the whole page -> The other side of my page is scrolling to the right so i can't see the whole content.

So I added "class="ui-responsive-panel"" into my page wrapper.

Now I have the same problem until I click a button, which i linked to my panel. This button hides the panel on first click and on second it reveals my panel and the right side content is scaling his width down (This is my aim).

What do I have to add, that this is already on page load done?

Thanks

EDIT:
My Code

```
<!-- Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page" class="ui-responsive-panel">

<!-- Panel -->
<div data-role="panel" id="Panel" data-display="reveal" data-position-fixed="true" data-swipe-close="false" data-dismissible="false" data-theme="none">
Content here
</div>

<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

Here my Content which I want to auto scale on page load

<!-- Panel shown on page load -->
<script>$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#Page', function(){       
    $( "#Panel" ).panel( "open");
});</script>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably add some code to your question first if you want anyone to be able to help ;)

Comment: @TravisJ Added my code into my question ;)

Comment: You want to have the `#page` visible with your panel open?

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP I already have this. I can use my panel and my site. But if I load the page the content on the right is not shown correctly. It's pushed to the side.. I want this but, the side's width should be automatically set for fitting in browsers window

Comment: You want both the page and the panel completely visible, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options here. First, I suggest looking into [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/). They do a lot of the styling so you do not have to.

Additionally, you can set a certain percentage width on each div. Just use the width:'value'%;.

Another thing you can do is use @media tag:

```
@media (min-width 300 && max-width: 480px) {
    #panel {
            width: 96px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but just in case someone is still trying to find an answer for this question.
I've had the same problem and fixed it in the following way:

```
    $(document).on("pagechange", function (event, data) {
        $('#Panel').panel("open");
    })
```

Now the html code for the panel is as follows:

```
<div  id="Panel" 
      data-role="panel" 
      data-display="push" 
      data-animate="false"
      data-dismissible="false" >
      <!-- /panel content -->
</div>
```

Where data-dismissible="false" is optional in case you wanted to keep the panel visible and data-animate="false" is optional in case you wanted to get rid of animation on page load.